# C++: Base class constructor with slightly different signature

Tags: c++

The following code compiles fine with two different compilers, one produces the expected result, the other one shows no output (gcc, C++98).

Class B inherits class A and calls its constructor with slightly different signature, passing a string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class A
{
protected:
  A ( string s )                   // <-- no const reference here
  {
    cout << "s: " << s << endl;
  }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
  B ( const string & s )
    : A( s )
  {}
};

int main ( int, char ** )
{
  B b( "Hi folks!" );

  return 0;
}
```

// Expected result: "Hi folks!"

Please note the const reference to the string in B's constructor, whereas the constructor of A passes the string by copy.

A debugger (ddd) shows that the string subjected for output, s, does not contain the passed-in characters but garbage. It doesn't seem to be default constructed. However, on one platform, the character string appears in the terminal, but not on a different one.

I wonder why there doesn't seem to be copy-constructor call while passing the string into A's constructor.

Comment: Which other compiler?

Comment: @rasteve I'd suspect _"C++ 98"_, whatever this is :-S ... (Borland maybe)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - I guess we are to also assume that this (C++98) compiler is the one that is not printing the expected string

Comment: C++98 means: g++ with C++11 not enabled.

Comment: @ClausWagner: Now I'm confused. What are the two compilers you are using?

Comment: @ClausWagner What compiler are you using and what is its version?  I cannot reproduce here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9941b0263101343f

Comment: Not real code, or ancient compiler, or wrong compiler settings.

Comment: C++98 means: g++ with C++11 not enabled (1998 standard).

The code snipped is the condensed problem from a bigger project here in our company. It runs under CentOS 6.6, x86_64, g++ 4.4.7. This platform fails to pass std::string per copy from a lower class into the constructor of the upper class (like in my condensed example). Note that in that project the constructors pass more than one parameter.

The other platform is a Slackware-based 32 bit machine running g++ 4.7.1. The output is as expected. 

I will provide some debugger output soon.

Comment: In case of passing-in the string as a const reference, indide A's constructor, it looks like:

(gdb) print s
$1 = (const std::string &) @0xbffff268: {static npos = <optimized out>, _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_p = 0x804a014 "Hi folks!"}}

In case of passing-in the string per value, the debugger prints (final part only):

_M_p = 0xbffff23c "\024 \004\boò\377¿ô¯è·xò\377¿.\212\004\bgò\377¿hò\377¿oò\377¿mÑÓ·\204³è·ôï\377·\024 \004\bô¯è·\220\213\004\bô¯è·"}}

Comment: The question is: is there some C++ rule forbidding parameters in a constructor to lose reference type while walking the hierarchy up, or something similar?

Comment: My first feeling would be a messed-up libc. Perhaps someone in your company rolls their own "optimised" version? The code you have posted here looks perfectly fine and should not cause any problems whatsoever with a non-broken compiler.

Comment: @Christian Hackl: both debugger dumps of the string inside A's constructor presented above have been made on the same machine: g++ 4.7.1.